# Send Confirm Email after Google form has been submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form with the following columns:

**Name | email | have_kids**

where Name is just text input, email is just an email, and have_kids is a yes/no radio button

ex. **dmkumar | myemail@gmail.com | Yes**

when the user submits the form, the data is sent to a google spreadsheet. I would like to have it set up so that if the user selected "Yes" to have_kids, then an email is sent to that user. Here is the code I have right now. I have a trigger event to run the function, from the spreadsheet, on the form submit.

Here is the code I have now (that is not working):

```
function emailConfirmation(e) {
  var userEmail = e.values[11]; //column k
  var check = e.values[14]; //column n


  /**
   * Un-comment this to use it for debugging
   */
  //for (var i in e.values) {
  //  Logger.log("" + i + ":" + e.values[i]);
  //}

  var subject = "Sending email from a spreadsheet";
  var message = "Hello World";
  if(check == "Yes")
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message);
  }
}
```

I am new to google scripting, so simple explanations would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "that is not working"? It's hard to know what's going on without an error, etc. Also, could you check and see if your emails are appearing in the Sent folder of the spreadsheet owner's email account?

Comment: When I submit a form, with some of my own data (and make sure to click yes on have_kids) I don't get an email. In terms of errors, the logs say that e is undefined if I run it from there, but I would expect that since no form was submited

Comment: Are you sure that e.values is actually filling in your userEmail var? Also, you should try a simple email to see if the `.sendEmail()` is working for you at all. Like `MailApp.sendEmail("test@gmail.com","Test","This is a test email");`.

Comment: I did that and it worked, I also figured out how to get the most recent form submission into the email. I'm gonna tinker with it some more, and I'll post it when I figure out the full problem.

Comment: Good to hear mate, good luck!

Comment: check in your sent mail - recently i have scripts sending mail on behalf to me (as demo / bug reports) and they are now auto read and in the sent box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I came up, because I'm sure people will stumble upon this page *sarcasm*

But it works great, none the less.

```
function emailConfirmation(e) {

  var userEmail = e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString(); //Where "Email Address" is the name of a column
  var kids = e.namedValues["Some of my guests are children who will attend the kids' camp."].toString();

  var subject = "Sending email from a spreadsheet";

  if(kids == "Yes")
  {
     MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, kids);
  }  
}
```

Comment: How do I implement this into my form though?

Comment: @imjp Hello! to implement this into your form you need to go to the script editor. To do that go to the table holding your form responses, and then go to "Tools" -> "Script Editor" and then copy/paste the script into the editor. Set you trigger to "On form submit". Look at this tutorial for using the Google Apps Script Environment http://www.google.com/script/start/